# Mist refusing to open following computer freeze/crash

Tags: mist

I've been using Mist on a Windows 10 machine for a few weeks, only minor issue I've encountered to date was an increase in system crashes, but today following a crash/freeze when I had to do a "hard reset" Mist refuses to launch. I click the icon (even with "run as admin") get the little blue spinning wheel for 3 seconds then nada. I've tried un-installing and reinstalling 5+ times already with no success. Also tried without the firewall just in case, but still no joy. I'm getting concerned as I have bids I need to reveal on the ENS now. Any help getting Mist back up working again would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have private keys to your addresses saved you can try deleting the `%APPDATA%/Ethereum` directory. This will delete the block chain and the key store files. You can backup the key store files by saving the `%APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore` first and then copying it back after.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, i've fixed it but disabling the others plugins, it seems to be a conflict there.

Comment: When you say "plugins" to what are you referring exactly? Plugins for what/where? Many thanks Sig!

Comment: disable them all. search how to disable plugins in your borwser.

Comment: Mist is its own browser.. which refuses to open. All other plug-ins from other browsers disabled. It's all good as I figured out how to reveal my bids using Parity instead. Thank u tho!